# Jquery.ready is firing earlier than Sharepoint Popup load

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I want to change the text of below popup from `New Folder` to `Add Image`. This popup is called from SharePoint code so I cannot call it through myself and specify the title Name

The only solution I have is to change it through jQuery.

[image]

I tried below code but it is firing too early.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");

function myCustomFunctionName() {
    if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length >= 2)
        $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[1].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
    else if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length == 1)
        $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[0].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
}
```

Also tried with jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length > 1)
        $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[1].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
    else
        $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[0].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
});
```

Upload.aspx Page Code

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadImageUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="GASCO.SC.Server.UploadImage.UploadImageUserControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 rowpad">
            <span>Click browse to locate a file to upload, then click Upload to save it to SharePoint.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 rowpad">
            <asp:Label ID="userMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 rowpad">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileBrowser" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="uploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadFileClick" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <asp:Image ID="previewImage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");

    function myCustomFunctionName() {
        if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length >= 2)
            $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[1].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
        else if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length == 1)
            $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[0].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
        else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                myCustomFunctionName();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where are you currently adding your code?

Comment: The Dialogue Page is Upload.aspx I am adding code in upload.aspx(popup)

Comment: Just to confirm - are you using a script editor web part, and is it the last web part on the page (after any data entry or form viewers).

Comment: I am adding code directly to upload.aspx page

Comment: I also added upload.aspx code behind

Comment: It's not that the code is called too early, it's the code that is wrong. Within the Upload.aspx there won't be any ".ms-dlgTitleText" class. This will be defined in the parent window, the child window won't have it. You have to revise your code accordingly

Comment: my code works if I open the popup and debug it through Chrome/IE it changes the title when I add code to console

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the code directly to the page using designer you should use a `Script Editor Web Part` (I think this may be called a `Content Editor Web Part` in SharePoint 2010), this will only fire once the page has fully loaded.

Comment: I am working on 2013 it is called script editor webpart. but still document.ready is firing before page is loaded

Comment: and when you use  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName"); instead of document.ready inside the script editor wp?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {    
        myCustomFunctionName();
    }

    function myCustomFunctionName() {
        if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length >= 2)
            $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[1].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
        else if ($(".ms-dlgTitleText").length == 1)
            $(".ms-dlgTitleText")[0].innerHTML = "Upload Image";
        else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                myCustomFunctionName();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

</script>
```